# zend form and zend x dialog

Tags: jquery, zend-form, zendx

I am new to zend im trying to make a login form within a dialog jquery but I am having no luck. I have set up zendX please could somebody help me as I am pulling my hair out with this one.

I have looked everywhere but I can not get anywhere with this.